# Do we need additional web server like Apache to handle multiple API requests from Dart server?

Tags: dart

I am starting with server-side Dart to have a "microservice" like architecture to provide REST API interface to IOT nodes.

As I have good experience with Flutter I want to use Dart for server-side application as well.

But I have a few queries regarding implementation as follows :

A. Do we need any additional web server like Apache to handle multiple simultaneous REST API requests from IoT devices/clients? Does Dart Server capable to handle large traffic independently?

B. Is there any document/case study of comparing **client request handling capability** of **Dart server side** Vs **Node Js** / **Python Flask**

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

A. Dart has its own HTTP server implementations, you don't need Apache, refer to [aqueduct](https://pub.dev/packages/aqueduct), [shelf](https://pub.dev/packages/shelf) or [angel](https://pub.dev/packages/angel_framework) for starters.

B. I don't know of any specific studies however you can find articles like [this](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/could-server-side-dart-replace-nodejs) if you google, in general the Dart VM performs well in this respect. Note that if you use Google cloud you can now also use Dart in the Cloud Run product if all you want to do is serve HTTP requests, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy)